# Get Menu instance in Titanium Android Module

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, chromecast, titanium-modules

I want to access and return a menu item in Titanium's Native android module but i found no documentation for accessing a menu in module. The documentation has only shown an example to create and return a native view using TiViewProxy class.Can we really do it? Because i need to create a module for Chromecast in android and according to the chromecast developer docs we need a menu item to work on.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender